# v-select with dynamic item list

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a v-select (don't forget the return-object or you won't get the ID):

```
<v-select v-model="selectedEmployee"
   :items="employee"
   item-text="name"
   value="id"
   return-object
   hide-details
></v-select>
```

I declare the array in data plus a helper array and a variable:

```
data: {
   employeeList: [],
   employee: [],
   selectedEmployee: null
},
```

I get the JSON array with a GET and put it into employeeList and then I wrangle the data to be displayed in the v-select:

```
for(i = 0; i < app.employeeList.length; i++) {
   app.employee.push({name: '', id: ''});
   app.employee[i].name = app.employee[i].lastname + ' ' + app.employeeList[i].firstname;
   app.employee[i].id = app.employeeList[i].id;
}
```

The employee.name is shown in the v-select and because of return-object you get the .id along with it. So the content of selectedEmployee is:

```
{name: 'Jane Doe', id: 0}
```

If you don't use return-object you only get what is shown in the v-select dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Showed you above how to make a dynamic item list for v-select and how to get a workable value out of it.
Took awhile to piece it together thanks to the bad / inaccessible documentation.
Maybe it's useful for somebody.